# ошибка при отладке программы в Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-basic, visual-studio-2013

Помогите разобраться! Захотел сделать свою первую программу. Наткнулся на сайт с пошаговой инструкцией создания проги типа Hello World на языке Visual Basic. Выполнил все как написано, и код вроде правильный, но при отладке выскакивает такая ошибка:

> Первый этап обработки исключения типа "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" в PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtens ion' threw an exception.' Line number '16' and line position '132'.
>
> Если для этого исключения имеется обработчик, выполнение программы может быть продолжено безопасно.

В интернете ничего годного не нашел. Может здесь кто-нибудь поможет. Только пожалуйста, можете объяснить языком, понятным не только опытному программисту.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj153219.aspx - ссылка на сайт

Код программы:

Class MainWindow

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If RadioButton1.IsChecked = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Hello.")
    Else : RadioButton2.IsChecked = True
        MessageBox.Show("Goodbye.")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Скрин ошибки, которая выходит после отладки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, все исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок, смотрите, в .NET есть механизим исключений - это возможность в любом месте программы выбрость "ошибку" наверх. Вызывающий код "наверху" может ожидать эту ошибку (как-то ее обработать и пойти дальше) или не ожидать (и тогда приложение просто упадет).

Механизим бросания "ошибок"-исключений состоит из нескольких шагов:

- Сам момент бросания исключения - "first chance" (первый этап в русском переводе) - назвается так, потому что это реально первый шанс хоть как-то про исключение узнать. До этого еще просто не было. По умолчанию - отладчик ловит этот шанс, пишет его в лог, но ничего не делает
- Пролет исключения вверх по стеку вызовов. Если исключение где-то было поймано (конструкцией Try/Catch) - то вызывается код обрабоки и на этом все заканчивается
- Если никто не изъявил желания обработать исключение - то наступает "second chance" - он же последний. Отладчик останавливается. Если отладчика нет - то приложение просто умирает.

Поведение отладчика на первом шаге регулируется настрокайми в диалоге Debug / Exceptions или Debug / Windows / Exception Settings для каждого вида исключений.

Ваша ошибка в логе означает что где-то в 16-й строке на 132-й позиции какого-то XAML файла была ошибка, парсер XAML ее бросил и где-то выше по коду эта ошибка заглушилась. Т.е. "first chance" был, "second chance" - не было.

Варианты что с этим делать:

- попробовать найти ошибку наугад, по номеру строки и позиции - вряд ли у вас много XAML-файлов. Скорее всего это какая-то опечатка / отсутствующая картинка или что-то подобное.
- поменять настройки для обработки исключений типа `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` - и посмотреть что именно и где падает.